# Incorrect dtype reading dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I use pandas dataframe to read a log file that looks like this

```
col1 col2 col3
2 3 string1
3 4 string2
5 6 string3

df = pd.read_csv(path-to-log, header=None)
df.dtypes

0 object
1 object
2 object
```

I expect the output to

```
0 float64
1 float64
2 object
```

Comment: something that I notice is that your log is space separated. have you tried adding a `sep = ' '` parameter? also in this case you shouldn't be using `header=None` since you already have that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log file contains headers, so you need not supply `header=None`. In addition, your delimiter is whitespace, so you can use `delim_whitespace=True`.

Note the first two columns are read in as integers instead of floats, since only whole numbers exist. Here's a demo:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

mystr = StringIO("""col1 col2 col3
2 3 string1
3 4 string2
5 6 string3""")

df = pd.read_csv(mystr, delim_whitespace=True)

print(df)

   col1  col2     col3
0     2     3  string1
1     3     4  string2
2     5     6  string3

print(df.dtypes)

col1     int64
col2     int64
col3    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use header=None

`df = pd.read_csv('test.log', sep=' ')`

Output-

```
col1     int64
col2     int64
col3    object
```